Makefile seems like some bugs when I put rule like "test_0.o: %.o: %.cpp"
I have Makefile2 of context below
test_0.o: %.o: %.cpp
    cp $< $@

In my current working dir, I have a file called test_1.cpp.
Then when I type command
make -f Makefile2 test_1.o

It shows the command being executed is
g++ -c -o test_1.o test_1.cpp

This is a bit strange. It shall be that there is no such rule test_1.o. Is this some known issue for makefile?

Does this answer your question? Struggling to understand Makefile implicit rules

You may simply creat an empty test_1.cpp. You shall then see it.

@chao the answer to the question you ask IS the answer to the question Joe points you to.  The reason why make builds test_1.o is that make has built-in rules that know how to turn a .cpp file into a .o file.  So while yes, it's true that the rule you wrote doesn't say how to create a test_1.o file, that doesn't matter because make has built-in rules that DO know how to do it, so make uses those.  If you want to avoid this, you should tell make to not consider its built-in rules by adding the -r option to your make command (or else remove the rule inside your makefile).

@Joe, Thanks. Sorry earlier I feel it is not relevant. But the article you refereed to me should be relevant as pointed out by MadScientist.

@MadScientist, Thanks for explain to me. I put "make -r" or MAKEFLAGS+=-r, then this won't be executed. But just one comment here for the rule: "test_0.o: %.o: %.cpp", should it at least match the rule test_0.o first? Now I type in "make test_1.o", rule itself is NOT matched. Also even if remove all the rules to have some empty makefile, if I type "make test_1.o" and my dir has test_1.cpp, it will still do gcc test_1.cpp. Is this expected as implicit rule?

I don't think I understand the question.  Your rule tells make how to build the target test_0.o, and only that target.  It has nothing to do with the target test_1.o.  So when you ask make to build test_1.o, of course it totally ignores a rule that describes how to build test_0.o.  Make basically does string matching, and the string test_0.o and test_1.o are not the same.  It doesn't matter to make that they are "mostly" the same.  Nothing about the presence, or not, of your rule to build test_0.o will matter when you ask to make build test_1.o.

Thanks @MadScientist! Just would like to confirm, when typing "make test_1.o", if no rule is matched, then it will check for implicit rule. And if it has the file ./test_1.cpp existing, tool will simply do "g++ -c -o test_1.o test_1.cpp" as some implicit rule matching. Hope this is expected behavior. Thanks again!

Yes.  Make wants to build a target.  If there's an explicit rule, make will use it.  If not, make will look for implicit rules.  If you've defined an implicit rule that matches the target, make will use that.  If you haven't, then make will look through its default set of implicit rules (if you haven't disabled them).  If one of those matches the target, make will use that.  If none of the above works, make fails with a message that it doesn't know how to build the target.

Just to point that, confusingly, test_0.o: %.o : %.c defines an explicit rule for test_0.o.  Even though this looks like a pattern rule and even though the name of this syntax is "static pattern rule", this actually defines an explicit rule for each of the targets on the left side.

thanks @MadScientist! It is now clear.
